# javascript: number counter live updated

Tags: javascript, counter, increment

I'm looking for a way to auto-increment a number every second, starting from a given date, and it must update live when I'm on the page.
For example, I decide that today at 12.00.00 the counter will start from 0 and then it must update every second (1 at 12.00.01, 2 at 12.00.02 and so on), I want to see the number changing live on the page. If two visitors load the page at the same second they will see the same number, and the grow of the number will be syncronized. How can I do it? I'm pretty new with javascript, I found this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dm6LL/5/

```
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var start = new Date("August 15, 2012 00:00:00").getTime();
var current;
update();

function update() {
var current = (new Date().getTime() - start)/1000*0.158+138276343;
amount.innerText = formatMoney(current);
}

setInterval(update,1000);

function formatMoney(amount) {
    var dollars = Math.floor(amount).toString().split('');
    var cents = (Math.round((amount%1)*100)/100).toString().split('.')[1];
if(typeof cents == 'undefined'){
    cents = '00';
}else if(cents.length == 1){
    cents = cents + '0';
}
var str = '';
for(i=dollars.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    str += dollars.splice(0,1);
    if(i%3 == 0 && i != 0) str += ',';
}
return '$' + str + '.' + cents;
}
```

that is similar to my goal, but it runs with money and it isn't exactly what I need.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. All you need is a minor change to your update function. And you can skip your 
`formatMoney` function.

Try something like this:

```
function update() {
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var current = (new Date().getTime() - start);
    var diffDate = new Date(current);
    var days = Math.round(current/oneDay);
    amount.innerText = days + ":" + diffDate.getUTCHours() + ":" + diffDate.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + diffDate.getUTCSeconds();
}
```

Basically, it gets the difference between start and current, and puts that into `amount` instead of the money value.

And there's the `oneDay` to calculate the days between the two dates.

You can format the output however you want, but this should get your started.